# Jeep Renegade 2015, engine temperature light

Tags: engine, cooling-system, jeep, instrument

This might be very stupid but I only have this car since 2 weeks (bought used). Today I noticed, that one of the red lights on the spectrum of the cooler temperature measure is on. It is the one closest to the H and there is no connection to all the white lights that rise until about the middle.

What does that mean? Do I need to refill fluid?

Thank you so much in advance. [image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm really not sure what you're talking about ... is there any way you could take a picture and insert it into your question, pointing out exactly  what you're talking about? I think it would really help here. Thanks!

Comment: Okay so I added a picture. I am horrible in explaining this and know nothing. So the red light on the top was not on earlier! What is the car trying to tell me?

Answer (score 1):

If you're are just talking about that single red square at the top of the arc, that's just there to show you were the hot zone is. If your white lights go up to this mark, then you have issues.  If your white lights stay in the middle after the vehicle is warmed up (which is what I'd consider "normal" range), everything is as it should be. Sounds like everything is copesetic to me.